# Cocos2D Ipad Game Scrolling

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I'm trying to make an Ipad game. For the game i want a scrolling background like the games: Hay Day & Clash of Clans. I used Cocos2D for this, with extension CCLayerPanZoom. But this don't give the nice scrolling effect (it not stops when you stop move with your finger but its easing? out and stops 'slowly'). And i think the zoom function of this extension class isn't 100% good.

Is there any solution or good class for this?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, boy. Having just tackled this problem in a recent prototype: I'm sorry for what's ahead. There are a couple of ways to do this, and neither are clean or simple.

I find that the more intuitive approach is to move the camera's position. You can do this by manipulating a scene's CCCamera. In this sense, you will scroll over the world as if flying above it in a plane. Collision detection between objects remains simple, because all objects maintain their 'real world' positions. If a sprite is at (100,100) in the game world, and you scroll your camera 500 to the left, the sprite still remains at (100,100).

Unfortunately, this introduces a lot of problems related to touch input. You can no longer easily check if 'this touch is on this node' because the touch coordinates are limited to the screen's resolution. If the camera is at (1000,1000) and you touch a sprite in the middle of the screen, that touch location registers at (320,280) (the middle of the screen). All touch calculations must now include the camera's offset, which can be tricky to remember and bothersome to include repeatedly.

The second technique is to put the world into a CCLayer, and then move that layer underneath the camera. I found this approach to be more of a hassle, so I didn't pursue it for very long.

Answer (score 0):

Use CCLayer and add all the child you want to move,into this layer.When you want to move everything,move CCLayer in update.

For converting layer coordinates  to real world coordinates use the below function :

-(CGRect)worldBoundingBox {

```
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize_.width,contentSize_.height);
return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, [self nodeToWorldTransform]);
```

}